# LinkedIn api client exception access to group denied?

Tags: android, linkedin-api

How can I post discussions on my linked Group from Android? I am using:

```
final GroupsApiClient client = factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessTokenValue,    tokenSecretValue);      
client.getGroupById(groupid);   
client.createPost("arg0", "arg1", "arg2");
```

but getting error `access to group denied` please can someone help? thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

**As of May 12, 2015:**

For access to `rw_groups`,  you will have to apply to become a member of a relevant [Partner Program](https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs) that provides the necessary API access to the `rw_groups` endpoint.

So, apply for partner status with LinkedIn, explaining what your integration is and how it works. If it meets the criteria of **"we feel that they’re providing value to members, developers and LinkedIn,"** then that endpoint will remain open for that app, and ONLY that app.

Comment: Do you have any idea about to get connnections? What scope it needs?

Comment: I think you will need `r_network` in the scope. Check this linkedin page on connections API. https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/connections-api

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to ensure that the **rw_groups** are granted to your application before you can post discussions to groups.

When going through your auth flow, make sure you add the rw_groups member permissions to this call:

```
POST https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken?scope=rw_groups
```

Then upgrade for an access token using the request token you just fetched and make the API call to post to a group.

Comment: thanks for your reply i am using access token and secret to directly make API call can u guide how to ad these permision ? in groups setting our in my android code

Comment: If you have an access token then you already know how to fetch the request token. The call I provided above shows you how to grant rw_groups permissions to your app. For more details you can review the Authentication document: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication

Comment: i used this permission in                                         final LinkedInRequestToken liToken  = oAuthService.getOAuthRequestToken("https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken?scope=rw_groups"); when i run my code it give authunication dialog when i click the button of sign in and allow then a toast appear " start downloading" and nothing else happens can u suggest anything ?? thanks!!

Comment: plzzz @Kamyar can u suggest me any thing ?? still no help :(

Comment: rw_groups is no longer enabled as of May 12, 2015.  Source: http://www.4sitestudios.com/insight/linkedin-about-get-more-restrictive-development